# How can i exclude certain files from a maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, properties-file

I have a maven project that includes a dependency of a local custom maven repository. However, there are files in it i do not want in my main project because they seem to override configs in the main project for some odd reason (application.properties). How can i exclude files (specifically application.properties) from a maven dependency?

Comment: Simple answer: No. You can only remove a dependency but not files which are within the dependency. I would argue that the dependency is the problem having property files in it... makes no sense.. and in particular if those are spring boot releated which looks a bit like that...

Comment: Please clarify the question! Maven dependencies and the application.properties file in the resources are two separate things.

Comment: The application.properties are quarkus related. The problem is, i can remove that part but the dependency includes classes which access hibernate components, meaning they will still need some application.properties config for hibernate or otherwise it wont compile correctly so it can be included in another maven project. I am starting to regret using Java and Maven for this project at this point, lol.

Comment: @Csisanyi One maven dependency has an application.properties file, and it ends up in the main projects uber-jar, overwriting the main application.properties fiel for some reason. I don't understand why a dependency's properties file would have higher priority than the main project ones. The main project ones will contain the configs necessary, but i cant compile the dependency without an application.properties due to it containing hibernate interfacing classes and it wont compile hibernate stuff if it is not configured (it warns that hibernate is ignored during compile).

Comment: Depends on how you create the uber jar. Maven Assembly Plugin may cause such issues.